# AWS S3: Copy files from S3 to Remote Server, with access credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to transfer data from S3 to a remote server. The data on S3 is protected, when I try to use AWS CLI on the remote server with the credentials I get an `AccessDenied` error.

However, when I'm in an E2 instance and use the same command, I can access the protected files.

Is it possible to transfer these files from an E2 instance to my remote server directly?

Previously I would:

1. AWS CLI S3 download the file to an E2 instance
2. Copy the file downloaded from E2 to my remote server

However, these files are large and I would perform the transfer in half the time if I was able to transfer from S3 to my remote server whilst in the E2 instance.

Is this possible? I tried

`aws s3 cp s3://protected-bucket/data/data.txt user_name@remote-server.edu:/path/to/data/`

And it failed. I also tried `aws s3 sync` and that failed too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS SDK boto3 to download the files from S3 to your remote server.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can access the files from your Amazon EC2 instance but not your remote server suggests that you are using a different set of credentials to access Amazon S3.

It is quite likely that an **IAM Role** has been assigned to your EC2 instance. If so, this automatically provides credentials that can be used by the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

You will need to create an IAM User for the Remote Server, then generate an Access Key and Secret Key for that IAM User. On the Remote Server, run `aws configure` and enter those credentials. You will need to assign permissions to that IAM User as necessary to grant access to the S3 bucket.

See: [Managing Access Keys for IAM Users - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html)